# Inertia removes the wrong item if I use prop as initial value?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

In the following case, Intertia.js seems to remove the wrong entry when [I pass the prop as initial value](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow). Am I doing something wrong?

***Example:***

**Laravel Controller:**

The following endpoint shows one issue with all its comments:

```
public function index(): Response
{
      $issue  = Issue::with('comments')->find(52);

      return Inertia::render('Dashboard/Issues/Test', compact('issue'));
}
```

There is also an endpoint to destroy a comment:

```
public function destroy(Comment $comment)
{
    $comment->delete();
    return back();
}
```

**Vue Page**
Displays all the comments:

```
<template>
<div>
  <input v-model="text">
  <button></button>
  <ul>
    <TestB v-for="comment in issue.comments" :id="comment.id" :initial-message="comment.message"></TestB>
  </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import TestB from './../../../components/comments/TestB.vue';

import {ref} from "vue";
const prop = defineProps(['issue']);
const text = ref('');
</script>
```

The TestB component stores the prop initialMessage into message (so its no longer reactive by parent)

```
<template>
  <li>
    <span>{{ message }}</span>
    <button class="text-red-600 p-1" @click="deleteC">DELETE</button>
  </li>
</template>

<script setup>
import {Inertia} from "@inertiajs/inertia";
import {ref} from "vue";

const prop = defineProps(['id', 'initialMessage']);
const message = ref(prop.initialMessage);

function deleteC(id) {
  console.log('DELETE');
  console.log(prop.id);
  Inertia.delete('/dashboard/issues/comments/' + prop.id);

}
</script>
```

Now the problem is, when I remove a line item, lets say the 2nd from top:

[image]

The suddenly it looks like the bottom element has been removed and `777` is still there:

[image]

When I reload the page, it appears again and element `777` is gone.

[image]

Why is that? I noticed that this only happens when I store `initialMessage` in `message`.

Comment: if you add `:key="comment"` attribute to `TestB` component will it solve problem?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka yes `:key="comment.id"` works. Just read https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key -